# html5 canvas not drawing triangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi i am trying to practice HTML 5 canvas. I just developed the code to make a triangle in a canvas. I am getting the canvas element using javascript and trying to draw a triangle in it. I don't know whats going wrong my javascript file is not getting linked or grabbing the canvas.

```
Html file code:
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset= "UTF-8">
   <style>

   #canvas {
       width: 400px; 
       height: 200px; 
       border: 1px solid red; 
 }

 </style>
 <script src="canvas.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<canvas id="tcanvas">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code to draw in the canvas:

```
  window.onload=init;
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tcanvas');
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

      canvas.fillstyle="#0000FF";
      context.lineWidth=3;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(50,100);
      context.lineTo(150,100);
      context.lineTo(100,50);
      context.lineTo(50,100);
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();


    }

 draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is `undefined` which means that your `draw` function is never invoked.

Check working example below which invokes `draw` on `window.onload`.

```js
function draw() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('tcanvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.fillstyle = "#0000FF";
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(50, 100);
  context.lineTo(150, 100);
  context.lineTo(100, 50);
  context.lineTo(50, 100);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

window.onload = draw;
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="tcanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does, you just have the `init` that is not defined and breaks up your code.
Possibly is defined elsewhere BUT contains error/s?
Another possible cause can be a canvasjs missing from where you linked it in your html, we cannot check that :)

Browser's console (F12) is your friend in situations like this.

Here is quick working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn2uv4gL/)

Note that this is the preferred way to show your code since it's more testable and easier to jump onto by others.

```
<canvas id="tcanvas">

  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tcanvas');
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

      canvas.fillstyle="#0000FF";
      context.lineWidth=3;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(50,100);
      context.lineTo(150,100);
      context.lineTo(100,50);
      context.lineTo(50,100);
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }

 #canvas {
       width: 400px; 
       height: 200px; 
       border: 1px solid red; 
 }
```